OpenIddict Claims Issue: The 'active' parameter is malformed or isn't of the expected type
I'm getting the following error on OpenIddict logs. It wasn't happening, and now it is and I can't figure out what is going on.
 The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+AttachWwwAuthenticateHeader`1[[OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext, OpenIddict.Validation, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f]].
18:29:46 info: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      => SpanId:9dda3f677f88be9b, TraceId:d1d28896e0567beabc507e15a81cc8c3, ParentId:385340d65fff25bb => ConnectionId:0HN57F4DPPO8A => RequestPath:/UpdateFirebaseToken RequestId:0HN57F4DPPO8A:00000007
      The response was successfully returned as a challenge response: {
        "error": "server_error",
        "error_description": "The 'active' parameter is malformed or isn't of the expected type.",
        "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2107";
      }.

I'm setting the active claim this way:
new(Claims.Active, (user.DeactivatedOn == null || user.DeactivatedOn.Value > DateTimeOffset.UtcNow).ToString().ToLowerInvariant(), ClaimValueTypes.Boolean),

So I'm at a loss as to what the issue is. I splunked the source code and it shows that a parameter is being tested for being a valid json boolean, but I can't tell where that parameter is coming from, so I can't identify what I need to fix.
Can someone suggest what is going on?
